# ajaxplorer: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm trying to install [ajaxplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info/) at a shared hosting in my home folder. When I navigate to the main page, I get an error:

```
is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
    File(/var/lib/php5) is not within the allowed path(s): 
    (/var/www//username/:/usr/sbin/sendmail:/usr/share/php
        :/home/www/appname::/usr/share/pear:/dev/urandom)
```

What might be the cause? How could I fix it?

There is php 5.3.3 installed, apache 2.2.16. I use ajaxplorer 4.0.4.

**EDIT:**

The problem is caused by this code part:

```
$tmpDir = session_save_path();
$this->testedParams["Session Save Path"] = $tmpDir;
if($tmpDir != ""){
   $this->testedParams["Session Save Path Writeable"] = is_writable($tmpDir);
```

Error appears in the last line, but I enclosed the context.

Comment: What script/line generated the error? Can you paste the relevant snippets?

Comment: Open basedir is a PHP security configuration parameter. Ask you hosting provider to change it, install in a location include in the open_basedir allowed paths. I assume 'other-path' points to your vhost dir?

Comment: @Jay Shah: I don't know, where exactly the problem ocures I'm just trying to install a downloaded application.

Comment: @Halfgaar: I added other paths. Provider won't change paths (btw. adding there /var/php5 seems to be not the best idea). I cannot install it in any other place.

Comment: @Halfgaar: I added code snippet what cause the error.

Comment: If you're having trouble with this particular explorer package why not try some of the others out there? Not all of them will work in all setups and trying to shoehorn them in is usually far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @John Gardeniers: do you possiblly know any replacement for ajaxplorer?

Comment: @mrzasa, not offhand but I recall that when I was searching for one ajaxplorer was just one of many I came across. I ended up using a different solution and can't even recall which ones I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding this to the top of the file:

```
session_save_path('/tmp');
```

If that works, you'll need to put it in a file that will be included by all other files for good measure (such as a configuration one where you specify your database details).

Alternatively, you can try adding a .htaccess flag or custom PHP.ini (former if you are using suPHP, latter if you are not). But let's try this first and see what happens.

AUTHOR'S EDIT:

Finally I had to put:

```
session_save_path(AJXP_INSTALL_PATH."/tmp"); 
define("AJXP_TMP_DIR", AJXP_INSTALL_PATH."/tmp");
```

in the conf/bootstrap_context.php file and it helped.

Comment: Finally I had to put: 
`session_save_path(AJXP_INSTALL_PATH."/tmp");
define("AJXP_TMP_DIR", PATH_TO_AJAXP_INSTALL."/tmp");`
in the `conf/bootstrap_context.php` file. Still this answer was helpful, so I', accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: tha second line was of course:
`define("AJXP_TMP_DIR", AJXP_INSTALL_PATH."/tmp");`